# Enter parameter value

Tags: ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2007. I have a query called `qryUPDATESTOCKS` that reduces the stocks from table products based from the quantity from table order.

Query:
`UPDATE tblPRODUCTS SET tblPRODUCTS.Stock = tblPRODUCTS.Stock-tblORDER.Quantity
WHERE tblORDER.ProductID=tblPRODUCTS.ProductID;`

To run this query when an order is saved, I added an action `OpenQuery` into my save button that runs the query.

But when I click the save order button, a dialog box appears saying "Enter Parameter Value". How do I prevent it from popping up?

Comment: You need to do it in VBA, or if you want to do it in Query, you need to pass int the order Number and use a **SubQuery** to get the Number of items to take away.

Comment: @PaulFrancis i want to do it in query, how to use a SubQuery?

Comment: Based on the Logic, you will be changing the Stock value for all products with the same ID. There is something fishy about the code. Check the answer, see if that would help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the Action Query in VBA, something like

```
Private Sub orderSaveButtonName_Click()
    Dim totAvailable As Long

    totAvailable = Nz(DSum("Stock", "tblPRODUCTS", "tblPRODUCTS.ProductID = '" & _
                            Me.ProductID & "'"), 0)

    CurrentDB.Execute "UPDATE tblProducts SET Stock = " & totAvailable - Me.Quantity & _
                      " WHERE tblPRODUCTS.ProductID = '" & Me.ProductID & "'"
End Sub
```

**Or** if you want to do it in Query, you need to pass the order Number and use a SubQuery to get the Number of items to take away. This could be complicated, using VBA is the straight forward solution.

Comment: it says "The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'prod001' the data type of ProductID from tblPRODUCTS is in text should i change the datatype? @PaulFrancis

Comment: If it is Text type, yes you need to enclose them in single quotes, check my updated answer.